# Change the value of an array index stored in a HashMap

Tags: java, collections

I was programming something and I was wondering if this is even possible to do.

I have a HashMap declared like this;

```
 Map<Integer,String[][]> rtePages=new HashMap<>();
```

now when I put something in the map i do this:

```
  rtePages.put(1,new String[5][2]);
```

My concern is that how would i change the values of the array generated?

Let's say I want to change [0][1] at key number 1?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do some experimentation first.

Comment: if i do rtePagesStore.set(1,[0][1]="something");  it doesn't really work because I've created an anonymous class with no reference variable to access it.

Comment: Show us an MCVE if you want an answer specific to something that is not spelled out in the question.  Your comment is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing arrays as values in a `Map`:

- To replace the array you use `map.put(key, newArray)`
- To update an element of the array you use `array = map.get(key)` to retrieve the array reference, and then you update the array value via the reference.  (You don't need to do a `put` unless you want to replace the array reference stored in the `Map`.)